# How to send TestNG emailable report through mail

Tags: testng

Please let me know the best way of automatically sending TestNG emailable report through mail without adding external jars.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is possible to do without adding external jars. The only way I see is to add mail.jar from JavaMail API and activation.jar.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ready to use code available to send mails. one of them is : http://assertselenium.com/2012/11/13/emailable-reports-for-selenium-scripts/ . You can call this in ant or maven after running all the tests.